# Sublime 3 - Toggle sidebar on tab double click

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, shortcut

I would like to toggle the sidebar when I double click on a file tab, does anyone know if it's possible?

I already created a `Default (Linux).sublime-mousemap` file to add some mouse interaction :

```
[
    {
        "button": "button1", 
        "count": 1, 
        "modifiers": ["ctrl", "shift"],
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "command": "goto_definition"
    },
    {
        "button": "button2", 
        "count": 1, 
        "modifiers": ["ctrl", "shift"],
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "command": "goto_css_declaration"
    },


]
```

Now the question is, how do you capture :

- the double click on mouse 1
- the click on a file tab